# Incrementing iteration through a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to incrementally iterate through a pair of hashes in Ruby? Should I convert them to arrays? Should I go an entirely different direction? I am working on a problem where the code is supposed to determine what to bake, and in what quantities, for a bakery given 2 inputs. The number of people to be fed, and their favorite food. They bake 3 things (keys in my_list) and each baked item feeds a set number of people (value in my_list).

```
def bakery_num(num_of_people, fav_food)
  my_list = {"pie" => 8, "cake" => 6, "cookie" => 1}
  bake_qty = {"pie_qty" => 0, "cake_qty" => 0, "cookie_qty" => 0}

  if my_list.has_key?(fav_food) == false  
  raise ArgumentError.new("You can't make that food")
  end

  index = my_list.key_at(fav_food)
  until num_of_people == 0
    bake_qty[index] = (num_of_people / my_list[index])
    num_of_people = num_of_people - bake_qty[index]
    index += 1
  end     

  return "You need to make #{pie_qty} pie(s), #{cake_qty} cake(s), and #{cookie_qty} cookie(s)."

end
```

The goal is to output a list for the bakery that will result in no uneaten food. When doing the math, the modulo would then be divided into the next food item.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `key_at`? Have you extended hash?

Comment: key_at is the point where I realized that hashes don't have indexes and that I needed to ask for help. It is not a real method, but I really wish it were.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to incrementally iterate through a pair of hashes in Ruby?

Since the keys of `bake_qty` conveniently have a `'_qty'` appended to them from their corresponding keys in `my_list`, you can use this to your advantage:

```
max_value = my_list[fav_food]    
my_list.each do |key,value|
    next if max_value < value
    qty = bake_qty[key+'_qty']
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use each, won't it go through every key,value pair? I need to be able to exclude any pair with a value greater than the key matching fav_food. For example: if I call bakery_num(24, cake) I want it to ignore the "pie" key.

Comment: @beaglebets Not sure if I understand you correctly but I've added code for `max_value` based on what you just said. In your example it should skip pie since 6 < 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use '[inject](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject)' method.

```
until num_of_people == 0
    num_of_people = my_list.inject(num_of_people)  do |t,(k,v)|
        if num_of_people > 0
            bake_qty["#{key}_qty"] += num_of_people/v
            t - v
        end
end
```

You can [sort your hash](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash) at the beginning to ensure that your first food is the fav food